# What does the filebrowser field actually do in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, ckeditor

The upload tab of image2 plugin looks like this -

```
{
            id: 'Upload',
            hidden: false,
            filebrowser: 'uploadButton',
            label: lang.uploadTab,
            elements: [
                {
                    type: 'file',
                    id: 'upload',
                    label: lang.btnUpload,
                    style: 'height:40px',
                    onChange: function(evt){
                        alert('file uploaded');
                    }

                },
                {
                    type: 'fileButton',
                    id: 'uploadButton',
                    filebrowser: 'info:src',
                    label: lang.btnUpload,
                    'for': [ 'Upload', 'upload' ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

Here in the `'tab'` details there is filebrowser field which is equal to `'uploadButton'` and filebrowser field is also in UI element object where it is equal to `'info:src'`.

I am not implementing Browse Server functionality, only upload functionality. I have implemented it but I want to understand how filebrowser plugin and filebrowser fields are facilitating it?

Can anyone here explain here a little bit in detail as CKEditor documentation does not tell much?

Answer (score 0):

The ck_config.js file has settings which determine the URL of the file browser for various purposes:

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '';
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '';
config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '';
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '';
config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '';
```

Basically this will be a webpage which appears in a roughly 600px-wide popup.
One of the GET parameters of this URL (automatically added) will be **CKEditorFuncNum** which determines the callback function for sending the results back to CK.

On selection of a file/path, you would typically do:

```
window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(ck_callback,pathrel2page);
```

where ck_callback is the CKEditorFuncNum value and pathrel2page is the selected file.

HTH.